# Using network library to pull down JSON

Tags: java, android, json, android-ion, ion-koush

I don't work with JSON often, but I was having a bit of trouble just doing it in Android with no other libraries. I stumbeled upon [Ion by Koush](https://github.com/koush/ion) and I'd like to use it to retrieve weather data for London. The JSON api I will be using is from [OpenWeather here](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk). As far as I can tell the JSON is valid, so I am now stuck on the Android side of things. My end goal is to have an object/String that reports londons `Main > temp`. This is my Android code, but I am unsure of what to do next. Any ideas?

```
private void getTemperature() {
Log.d(TAG, "2");
final JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
Ion.with(this, "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk")
.asJsonObject().setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
    // do stuff with the result or error
    Log.d("TAG", "Complete");
    //json = result;
    }
    });
}
```

My code gets to the "Complete" log statement, but now I'm trying to set result to my json Object I created, so I un-comment `//json = result`, but I get an error in Eclipse. Any help? I would like this method to simply output the `Main -> Temp` which (as of right now) is 284.51.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typical ion usage is aynchronous, but it has synchronous support.
Instead of using setCallback (async), use get() (sync) to get it back synchronously. This will block your current Thread though.

```
final JsonObject json = Ion.with(this, "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk")
.asJsonObject().
.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you marked the json variable as final, I don't think you can reassign it to the point to result in your onCompleted() method.

I would recommend creating an AsyncTask with an HttpClient to actually pull the JSON.  I think this would be simpler and cleaner.

HttpClient Example
http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/

Comment: 1. If I remove `final` I get an error under `json` in `json = result`. "Cannot refer to a non-final variable json inside an inner class defined in a different method" The quick fix says to add final. 2. The ion library by Koush is also Async.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually parse the JSON, I'd recommend Googles GSON package

Comment: Ion accomplishes Async JSON via GSON.